# Link php interpreter from Docker to bash somehow

Tags: php, bash, docker

I'm trying to use my docker php as an interpreter in my terminal. What I need:

- I don't keep my dev envs on my host os. That's important to keep it isolated
- It should be available as `$php` or `$/usr/bin/env php`
- I'd like to be able to run something like phpcs in my vim. It requires that thingy above.

I've tried this:

```
alias php='docker-compose exec php php'
```

But it's not available through `/usr/bin/env`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` tries to locate the executable via the `$PATH` variable, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12749

So if you put your command in to a script called PHP and add it to your `$PATH` before other PHP executables, it might work.